# How to pass a string parameter contains 'double quote' cucumber feature file

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

I have to pass string which contains 'double quote' symbol as parameter in feature file.
ex: And Get the enabled play books of  "HPC "Big memory" nodes"

here HPC "Big memory" nodes is single string/sentence.

Answer (score 2):

Gherkin supports both options: ' and  ", so try to combine

```
Gherkin:
Then I should see "Hello \'World\'" text
Then I should see "Hello \"World\"" text


@Then("I should see {string} text")
public void i_should_see1(String string) {
    System.out.println("Test:"+string);
}
```

Comment: Isnt cucumber smart enough not to require escaping `'` once they are encountered inside `"..."`.

Comment: it is, so should work with and w/o escaping @AlexeyR.

Comment: @Maria - Unfortunately it didn't worked for me. Just avoid confusion here i am passing parameter "HPC "Big memory" nodes", but cucumber considering it as two parameters "HPC " and " nodes". Moreover i need this parameter as it is to pass the to dynamic xpath.

Comment: What if in your feature file: Given HPC 'Big Memory' nodes                   ,and in your code: @Given("Given HPC {string} nodes") public void hello(String value) { } ... It has to work. In case you can provide an error log if it won't work, we can review the issue more.